# How do I store my private api key on Vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli, dotenv

I read the documentation on Vue CLI and I wanted to make sure if I understand it correctly.

The documentation says,

`Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.`

So does that mean I should store my private key without the prefix VUE_APP? For example,

```
VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_KEY=not_secret_key
SECRET_KEY=secret_key
```

Is it correct way to store my secret key?

Comment: It's probably better to serve the UI from a different container/app as the backend; but if they're both on the same server, yes, that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: There is USUALLY no such thing as a secret key on the front end, think about it. If you load it into javascript or html, any user can see it as well. Maybe whoever is looking at this question is mistaken. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can store your key either in  `VUE_APP_NOT_SECRET_KEY=not_secret_key` or  `SECRET_KEY=secret_key`, there is no difference from security point of view, any one with a minimal front end skill get read this values from the browser.

The only difference is that if you use the `VUE_APP_*` prefix your variable will be in the process.env, and will be replaced by Vue in compile time using the DefinePluing.

cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables –

**NOTE WELL**: Anything you store in the Vue app is not secret.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `.env` file in the root of the project, next to `package.json`

In that file, you can create your environment variables as
`VUE_APP_SOME_KEY="someValue"`

Make sure the name starts with `VUE_APP_`

Then where ever you want to use it you can do
`process.env.VUE_APP_SOME_KEY`

Also don't forget to add `.env` file to `.gitignore`

Comment: Do not store any secrets in your app! Environment variables are embedded into the build. Anyone can view them by inspecting your app’s files.

Answer (score 0):

Keys should not be stored in environment variables as they will be accessible on the client

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a product like Key Vault from Microsoft. Key Vault is part of Azure services.

Best practice in the industry is to store your secrets on another server.

Microsoft provides such a way through key vault and can be easily [implemented](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets).

There are other products out there. See the azure keyvault [competitor's list](https://sourceforge.net/software/product/Azure-Key-Vault/alternatives)

Edit : I also forgot to mention, you cannot at this time use KeyVault per example directly on frontend app (single page app). You need to split the backend and frontend for it to work, otherwise you will not be able to hit the keyvault client.