# How do i securly save content in an vue SPA app

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

Lets assume i have some secret content i will hide in my Vue app, the following string:

```
This is really secret
```

This content i put in my `LoggedInHome.vue` Component:

The Component is only available when the User logged in. Then, i test it by

```
npm run preview
```

Now i check the source code of the Vue app via browser, the generated minified js, where the whole SPA lives in ( in my case: `view-source:http://localhost:5050/assets/index.6d93f8ef.js` )

In the `index.6d93f8ef.js` file, i can see the secure string. This is not what I'm expecting.

I want to hide this so nobody except Logged in Users should see this content in the LoggedInHome Component. How do i solve this?

Is this by design ( the whole SPA + content lives in the Browser ) or do i miss something?

**Edit**: I guess this is the answer : [How do I store my private api key on Vue.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64617828/how-do-i-store-my-private-api-key-on-vue-js-app)

Comment: Don't put it at all in the client-side. Anything that you write in HTML, JS, CSS will be visible in the browser. Leave anything that must be keep secret from the user in the server and never send it away.

Comment: The described case (nobody except Logged in Users) isn't the same as the linked question (nobody at all). In the first case. In the former case data is supposed to be fetched from the backend for an authorized user, in the latter case it should be used only on the backend

Comment: Is there any protection against unauthenticated users downloading said source code? No? Then it's not protected.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other comments said, you should not put secrets client-side.
You could grab it with an api call which only allows admins to access the secret.